# Android Java Get simple .php page content into a String and save to internal storage

Tags: java, android, string, download, internal-storage

I'm developing an app. That app needs to get the content of a simple .php URL, and save it as a String. 
The problem is that it is a very long String (VERY LONG) and it get's but in half. Take this link as an example:
http://thuum.org/download-dev-notes-web.php
With this code

```
URL notes = new URL("http://thuum.org/download-dev-notes-web.php")
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(notes.openStream()));
String t = "";
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
 t = inputLine;
fOut = openFileOutput("notes", MODE_PRIVATE);
fOut.write(t.getBytes());
// Added This \/ to see it's length when divided, and it is not nearly as much as it should be
System.out.println(t.split("\\@").length);
```

Can someone tell me how would I be able to download that into a String, and save it into the internal storage without it getting cut? Some why it looks like it gets only the last x digits...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you're overwriting your `String t` in every iteration of the while-loop. Try this:

```
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine = "";
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(inputLine);
    }
    fOut = openFileOutput("notes", MODE_PRIVATE);
    fOut.write(result.toString().getBytes());
```

It creates a mutable StringBuilder and uses the resulting (immutable) String in the write call.

edit: I also recommend to always use curly brackets to indicate end of loop bodies, ommiting those can quickly lead to bugs, just check #gotofail for a recent example ;-)